# SSIS - Redirecting data to different Outputs

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm developing a custom component that inherits from a PipelineComponent in SSIS.

This is the "ProvideComponentProperties" snippet of code:

```
IDTSOutput90 output = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New();
output.Name = "Output";
output.SynchronousInputID = input.ID;
output.ExclusionGroup =0;
m_DefaultOutputId = output.ID;

IDTSOutput90 discardedOutput = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New();
discardedOutput.Name = "Discarded Output";
discardedOutput.SynchronousInputID = output.SynchronousInputID;
discardedOutput.ExclusionGroup = 1;
//I don't want it to be an output
//discardedOutput.IsErrorOut = true; 
m_DiscardedOutputId = discardedOutput.ID;
```

And then in the process input i have this:

```
while (buffer.NextRow())
{
    bool discarded = true;
    if  (//Discard condition)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < input.InputColumnCollection.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            //Write to buffer
        }
        discarded = false;
    }
    if (discarded)
    {
        buffer.DirectRow(discardedOutput.ID);
    }
    rowIndex++;
}
```

The problem I am having that is not redirecting the row. The row keep its flow in the "Output" output instead of going through the "Discarded Output".

Answer (score 0):

I think the ExclusionGroup needs to be the same for both outputs (make output.ExclusionGroup=1 instead of 0).